# Excel VBA Selenium FindElementXpath variable error

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, for-loop

hi im trying to selenium for loop in excel vba. the code gives me only first path value for all loop. how can i correct it?

```
For i = 1 To 3
'On Error Resume Next
Sheets(1).Cells(cc, 1).Value = driver.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='itemDiv']/div['i']/a[1]").Attribute("href") 
Sheets(1).Cells(cc, 2).Value = driver.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='itemDiv']/div['i']/div[1]/a/h5").Text  
Sheets(1).Cells(cc, 3).Value = driver.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='itemDiv']/div['i']/a[2]/span[1]").Text  
Sheets(1).Cells(cc, 4).Value = driver.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='itemDiv']/div['i']/a[2]/span[2]").Text  
Sheets(1).Cells(cc, 5).Value = driver.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='itemDiv']/div['i']/p/small").Text 
cc = cc + 1
Next i
```

Comment: the xpath string reads `i` as character, not as iterating counter. So change it to `"//*[@id='itemDiv']/div['" & i & "']/a[1]"` by joining the actual counter values via ` & ` operator :-) @AhmDen

Comment: While @AhmDen's answer is technically correct, it relies upon VBA's automatic data type conversion, which I'm not a big fan of. Therefore I personally would use `CStr()` to convert the number into a string: `...div['" & CStr(i) & "']`. Assuming ofc that i is defined as a numeric (integer) data type.

Comment: nothing changed.`Sheets(1).Cells(cc, 1).Value = driver.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='itemDiv']/div[1]/a[1]").Attribute("href") Sheets(1).Cells(cc, 1).Value = driver.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='itemDiv']/div[2]/a[1]").Attribute("href")` worked perfectly but `"//*[@id='itemDiv']/div['" & i & "']/a[1]"` and `...div['" & CStr(i) & "']` writes only first element all for loops

Comment: Omit the single apostrophs `'` within the `div[]` brackets? @AhmDen

Comment: `div[" & CStr(i) & "]` this works. thanks